# LXC: Can I guarantee a certain level of CPU resources to a given container

Tags: architecture, lxc, container

We're going to use LXC to multi-purpose our hardware while keeping the various applications easy to manage, develop, upgrade, and logically segregated.

What I want to know is if I can **guarantee certain resources**, such as CPU, **to a certain container**.

We have one process which will run in its own container that is a critical component of our application infrastructure. I'd like to dual purpose that box and let a non-critical, but resource-intensive, component (the worker node) reside in a separate container on the same hardware, but to be safe I want to guarantee that, when the critical component needs CPU, it gets it, at the expense of the non critical component.

I'd rather do this at the container level rather than jury-rigging the application with `nice` or something like that because this configuration is only valid on one piece of hardware, on other boxes the worker node stands alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days further research... cgroups!

This video from Red Hat sums it all up brilliantly. Now get it implemented!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KX5QV4LId_c